# Connecting R to Snowflake via ODBC with SSO and Web Authentication

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc, single-sign-on, webauthenticator

I'm trying to connect R Studio to Snowflake via ODBC but we're on SSO and web authentication. A lot of the articles I've found are based on a user having a user ID and password authentication access.

I'm using the odbc, DBI, dplyr and dbplyr packages

Thanks

Comment: Have you set the **authenticator = "externalbrowser"** in the connection string and it's not working?

Comment: Yeah, it gave me an error. Seems that it's still requiring a password. I can authenticate through external browser in DBeaver though...

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1118: 01S00: [Snowflake][Snowflake] (31) 
      Password not found.
      [Snowflake][Snowflake] (17) 
      1 invalid keys are found in the connection string: AUTHMETHOD